CSP blocking to open a pdf using blob
Am showing a pdf in new tab like below
I have enabled CSP in my application, the pdf is broken in new tab due to inline style.
this.pdfService.downloadPdf(this.id).subscribe((data: Blob) => {
        let fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(data);
        window.open(fileURL);
    });`````


can you try adding object-src 'self' to check if it allows, also try other options, like specifying the URL that opens in another tab.
